# Are all complex numbers multi-valued/periodic? What about functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

For example, a complex number like $z=1$ can be written as $z=1+0i=|z|e^{i Arg z}=1e^{0i} = e^{i(0+2\pi k)}$.

$f(z) = \cos z$ has period $2\pi$ and $\cosh z$ has period $2\pi i$.

Given a complex function, how can we tell if it is periodic or not, and further, how would we calculate the period? For example, how do we find the period of $f(z)=\tan z$?

Comment: What do you mean by a complex number being multi-valued or periodic? That makes no sense.

Comment: i guess that they can be represented in multiple ways in polar form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you write $1=\exp(2\pi i k)$, you are really making a statement about how th the exponential function acts on the complex numbers. Namely, the exponential map is many-to-one: For each integer $k$, the imaginary number $2\pi i k$ is mapped by the exponential to $1$. By contrast, the logarithm inverts this: $1$ can be mapped to $0$, or to $2\pi i$, and so forth, depending on which branch of the logarithm is chosen.

What's crucial, then, is that these are properties of the functions mapping complex numbers to complex numbers themselves, not of the complex numbers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Complex numbers are *not* multi-valued or periodic. The $\arg$ "function" can be seen as multi-valued.